# Can't ssh through command prompt after using ssh in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, ssh-keys, openssh, vscode-remote

When I ssh using the window's command prompt, it worked and in the .ssh folder it created a "known_host" file. I then used VScode ssh extension to remote control, and it created a "config" file. Then, when I disconnect the connection in VScode and ssh using command prompt, it shows: Bad owner or permissions on C:\Users\bellz/.ssh/config. I can only ssh again if I delete the "config" file. Is there a way I can ssh in terminal without deleting the "config"?

I tried changing the permission of the "config" file and it doesn't work.

Comment: What are the permissions on that file?

Comment: @JimRedmond From everyone

Comment: does anything in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/119 or https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/3210 or https://superuser.com/q/1212402/1749748 help?